# Delete all lines that contain a substring between two indexes

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need to delete all the lines containing some string in a given file if it appears between the 3rd and 10th position (character).

This is my `sed` command:

```bash
sed '/^.\{3\}le.\{10\}/d' file-name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed '/^.\{3\}.\{0,5\}le/d' filename
```

The POSIX BRE regular expression means:

- `^` - start of string
- `.\{3\}`  - any three chars
- `.\{0,5\}` - any zero to five chars
- `le` - a `le` substring.

So, 3 + 5 is 8, and `le` length is 2, so the pattern only removes lines that contain `le` in between the third and tenth positions.

You may also use `awk`:

```sh
awk '!index(substr($0,4,6), "le")' filename
```

Here,

- `substr($0,4,6)` - gets a 6-char substring starting with the fourth char
- `!index(..., "le")` - returns true if the substring above does not contain `le`.